# Read line by line gzip big file

Tags: python

I need to know how many times a number appears in a gzip file with  2912232966 lines , I have the following:

```
import gzip
from itertools import islice

count=0
f = gzip.open(file,'rb') 
for line in f:
lin = line.decode('utf-8')
number = lin[:lin.index('\t')]
if number == '2719708':
  conunt+=1
```

but i get this:
'CRC check failed 0xabc8df68 != 0xba1760acL'

it only works 
only works up to 400000000 lines, help please

Comment: can you unzip the file without errors with `gunzip`?

Comment: Perhaps you could run gunzip as a subprocess and read its output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link to [zlib](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html)

quote from jiffyclubs answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732709/unzipping-part-of-a-gz-file-using-python)

> The issue with the gzip module is not that it can't decompress the
>   partial file, the error occurs only at the end when it tries to verify
>   the checksum of the decompressed content. (The original checksum is
>   stored at the end of the compressed file so the verification will
>   never, ever work with a partial file.)
>
> The key is to trick gzip into skipping the verification. The answer by
>   caesar0301 does this by modifying the gzip source code, but it's not
>   necessary to go that far, simple monkey patching will do. I wrote this
>   context manager to temporarily replace gzip.GzipFile._read_eof while I
>   decompress the partial file:

This looks to be exactly what you need....

Go to that link and read the entire respose.

---

Found by searching google for a stackexchange link to "python gzip crc check failed"
first result